# Inject DAO into CXF Service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, dependency-injection, cxf

I am trying to inject a DAO into an CXF Service. For this purpose I am using xml configuration.

In my app-servlet.xml I've added following entry:

```
    <bean id="blogService" class="blog.BlogEntriesImpl">
        <property name="blogDao" ref="blogDao" />
    </bean>
```

blogDao bean is also defined in this file.

The service is configured in another xml file:

```
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <jaxws:endpoint id="blogService" implementor="blog.BlogEntriesImpl"
    address="/Blog1" />
```

BlogEntriesImpl implements the service interface. It has a dao attribute and a setter method.

I debugged the application and found out, that one instance of BlogEntriesImpl is instanciated on the start and it has the dao attribute. I would say it is done by the bean configuration from the app-servlet.xml.

However, when I call the service, a NullPointerException is thrown. Here is another instance of BlogEntriesImpl being used.

To solve the problem I declared the dao attribute in the service implementation class (BlogEntriesImpl) as static. The variable is set on the start of the application. But I don't like this solution.

Is there a better way to inject a dao into the CXF service?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, there are actually two instances of your `BlogEntriesImpl` class, one created by Spring and one by Apache CXF. You must explicitly ask Apache CXF to use Spring bean rather than providing a class. Check out [Writing a service with Spring](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html), looks like you have to replace:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="blogService" implementor="blog.BlogEntriesImpl" address="/Blog1" />
```

with:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="blogService" implementor="#blogService" address="/Blog1" />
```

If Apache CXF can't find bean with name `blogService`, consider moving it to main context from Spring MVC context (`app-servlet.xml`).